# Tag synonyms for voting

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Post here tag synonym proposals for voting.

For example: what tags should by synonyms of "quantum-mechanics"? See also [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4007/2451) meta post.

This post can also be used to suggest minor changes to a tag, e.g. [pluralization](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4677/2451).

1. Use the format [write-here-synonym](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-here-synonym)→[write-here-master](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-here-master) in your answer.

   (Copy-pasteable template: `[tag:write-here-synonym]→[tag:write-here-master]` .)
2. Before creating a new answer, please go to [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) or to https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/write-here-master/synonyms (where the write-here-master part of the URL is appropriately replaced) and check that your tag synonym has not already been proposed.
3. Moreover, it is recommended to only suggest a tag synonym if the tag is used at least twice. (Tags that are only used once will expire automatically by themselves after some time.)

Comment: There do appear to be some restrictions on voting for tag synonyms, though (I tried to vote for one - I forget which - and got a popup box warning that I couldn't)

Answer (score 5):

[biology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) → [biophysics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biophysics)

Every biology question should be about the physics part.

Comment: having good tag wikis, and particularly good excerpts, would probably be much more helpful than a simple synonym.

Answer (score 2):

[half-life](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life) → [radioactivity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radioactivity)

The new tag [*half-life*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life) introduced is really a subset, and radioactivity is sufficient for identification purposes and subsuming.

Comment: Also, [relevant chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22108640#22108640), and thereabouts.

Comment: I don't think the argument holds. [tag:electromagnetic-radiation] is a subset of [tag:electromagnetism]; should we merge *them*? [tag:half-life] adds perfectly valid descriptive information about the question, above and beyond [tag:radioactivity]. (In addition, it's not *really* a subset - every exponential decay has a half life. Try doing radiation biophysics without [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_half-life), for instance.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - Alright that's your opinion. And while the argument about half-life in bio is technically right, I don't think there has been enough of it on this site anyways for the argument to hold. For instance, this is [your sample space](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbiophysics%5D+half+life), a total of three results! And with the bio aspect left out, I don't think a separate half-life tag is of any great use. Plus, there are only 175 questions tagged with radioactivity (as opposed to the bigger ones, like QM), and ... (contd.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - (contd.) ... and [118 of these 175](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bradioactivity%5D+half+life) also feature half-life in it. Thus, half-life takes a substantial amount of radioactivity load. With this tag added today, and assuming it survives, you are talking about potentially re-tagging 118 posts which already have the 'radioactivity' tag, with 'half-life'. It looks like a useless task to me to be honest, but that's my opinion, and I can't vote on my post. But the stats seem to be favoring my proposal. :)

Comment: That pretty much misses the point. The question is not "are all half-life questions about radioactivity?" but rather "must all radioactivity questions be about half-life?" (on which your stats are abundantly clear). Unless the answer to the latter is yes, the tag helps distinguish those that do from those that don't. I don't see the reason to get worked up about it, though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - No one's worked up here, but a justification (i.e. what I call a justification) was necessary. Alright, peace!

Comment: I don't see why the question would be 'must all radioactivity Qs be about half-life' here. Half-life is (suggested to be) a subset of radioactivity, which means that Qs about half-life are about radioactivity though not every radioactivity Q will necessarily be about half-life.

Comment: @KyleKanos - Yes, and there appear to be only three bio-relevant half-life questions, so your point makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

[radio-frequency](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-frequency)→[radio](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio)
24 vs. 54 questions tagged; no wikis for either.

Answer (score -3):

I've suggested *subatomic* as a synonym for *particle-physics*.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/particle-physics/synonyms

Answer (score -5):

[coordinate-systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-systems) → [reference-frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-frame)

Comment: I disagree with those tags being synonyms. When for example asking about light cone coordinates [tag:coordinat-systems] is appropriate whereas [tag:reference-frame] is not. Whereas when asking about inertial reference frames, the converse holds. I have to think it further to state why I disagree from a more clear rational state of view than just using examples ...

Comment: @Dilaton So you're saying more that coordinate systems are a mathematical construct, which is then used by a reference frame for physical situations rather than purely a mathematical one?

Comment: still thinking about it ... I would say coordinate systems are yes a mathematical construct to represent things, but the physics should not depend on this representation, whereas it makes a physical difference if a reference frame is accelerated or inertial, you can not just switch between them by coordinate transformations. Darn, it is too late for me to think clearly today :-/...

Answer (score -7):

[observational-astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observational-astronomy) → [astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy)

Comment: -1 astronomy is broader.

Answer (score -8):

[photon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photon) → [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation) 
[photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photons) → [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation) 
[virtual-photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-photons) → [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation)

It would be nice if all things related to propagating electromagnetic fields would be covered by [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation). Additional tagging with [electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism) and [quantum-electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-electrodynamics) could then be used to distinguish between the classical and QFT description, with [particle-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-physics) for the [HEP](http://example.net) questions.

The reasoning here is that [photon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photon) is not sufficient to distinguish between a classical and QFT treatment either. [thermal-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermal-radiation) would still be a strict and helpful subset of [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation).

Comment: -3 EMR can be classical EM too.