# tag:classical-electrodynamics and tag:electromagnetism

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag synonyms for voting](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/tag-synonyms-for-voting)

We currently have three tags (and many others):

- [electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism)
- [classical-electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-electrodynamics)
- [quantum-electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-electrodynamics)

In my opinion, [classical-electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-electrodynamics) should be a synonym to [electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism), covering everything that is governed by the classical Maxwell equations, such as the Lorentz force, magnets and most other things you can think of. It would include the Lorentz invariant treatment of electromagnetism and the first introduction of electromagnetism to quantum mechanics as classical fields. This fits what one gets when searching [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism) for ‘Electromagnetism’.

It would leave [quantum-electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-electrodynamics) as the clear counterpart for the QED approach arising from QFT.

The tags [electric-engineering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-engineering) and [electric-circuits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-circuits) (there is currently a synonym suggestion for them) would be unchanged, of course, and still make sense.

Comment: Rather than opening a new meta post for every tag synonym, this meta question should have been a meta answer [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think it's such a bad idea here, it'll get more attention this way. But that's just me.

Comment: @Qmechanic Ouch, sorry. Posted it as an answer there. :)

Comment: But if the synonym suggestions are kept together as answers to one question, this is more ordered and systematic. Answering the question as Qmechanic says will pump it and give everybody an incentive to look at all the already proposed synonyms too.

Comment: OK then, I'll close this as a duplicate.