# Redundant tags II

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[Redundant tags I](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/redundant-too-specific-tags-about-specific-variables-etc) has  been made more specific to overtly specific tags. Here are some which don't even seem to be about physics.

[x-ray-crystallography](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-crystallography)   [laws-of-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-physics)   [approximations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximations) [complex-number](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-number)     [affine-lie-algebra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affine-lie-algebra)   [laboratory-safety](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laboratory-safety)

Answer (score 2):

[x-ray-crystallography](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-crystallography) This isn't very specific. Common technique in experimental physics.

[laws-of-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-physics) Slightly metaphysics-y, but not that bad a tag. it's ambiguous though, I guess we could get rid of it. Not too certain about that

[approximations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximations) Sort of a meta tag in the sense that it doesn't denote a topic (however that doesn't seem to be the tpe of met tag that's disallowed, since most other sites have similar tags). But otherwise approximations are there in many different physics topics.

[complex-number](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-number) similar as above. Used in many places (circuit analysis, optics are two examples I can come up with)

[affine-lie-algebra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affine-lie-algebra) Probably too specific as it has only 2 questions. I don't know how broad the topic/application is.

[laboratory-safety](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laboratory-safety) is on topic (I think), and a pretty interesting tag to have.

Comment: @Dimension10 Hmm, I don't think so myself :/

Answer (score 1):

Here I do not quite agree that all of the tags mentioned in this question should be burnicated (generally I think all the tags we have should denote meaningful physics terms):

- [x-ray-cristallography](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-cristallography) is a meaningful method to investage the
  structure of materials in the field of material sciences, so it seems
  a good one.
- [laws-of-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-physics) seems a bit unspecific
- [approximations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximations) seems ok for questions that ask about about
  particular approximations needed in different contexts
- [affine-lie-algebra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affine-lie-algebra) is a good meaningful technical tag for
  technical questions (it came from TP.SE), even though it is not
  heavily populated I still dont give up that the kind of questions
  that needs this kind of tags will increas again ;-)
- [labor-savety](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labor-savety) looks slightly off topic to me ..

.

Comment: @Dimension10 it depends of course, for example if the theoretical fraction of questions would increase again, it could be useful to have things like [tag:clifford-algebras], [tag:fiber-bundles], etc too. And I still want [tag:F-theory] ... ;-P !

Comment: @Dimension10 yeah, I somehow dont agree with this merge either, I'd prefer having [tag:string-theory], [tag:m-theory], and [tag:f-theory] seperately, but that is just me ... ;-)