# Redundant tags III

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

After [Redundant tags I](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/redundant-too-specific-tags?rq=1) and [Redundant tags II](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/redundant-tags-ii), Redundant tags III is about tags about specific objects, meaningless to tag a question with .

[graphene](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphene)  [air](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air) [water](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water)  [earthquake](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthquake)      [nebulae](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nebulae)      [asteroids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asteroids)   [aircraft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft)   [gauss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauss-law) (this is the *only* maxwell equation tag we have. This is the closest redundant tags                                                                I could post     put this on .    )

Comment: Suggestion to several of your recent tag posts: Replace the meta tag [tag:burninate-request] with the meta tag [tag:tag-synonyms]. Burninate requests requires outside intervention from the SE team, and should only be used in a few exceptional cases. Usually we can handle this ourselves within Phys.SE via tag synonymizations and tag merges.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Ok. I didn't retagg II though, as it is still more-of a burninate request .

Answer (score 3):

[graphene](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphene) is a pretty big field in solid state physics. It has applications in the implementation of quantum computation.

[air](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air) probably isn't necessary and can be merged with one of the fluid tags

[water](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) ditto

[earthquake](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthquake) merge with [geophysics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geophysics)?

[nebulae](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nebulae) this isn't really a specific object as nebulae are quite a vast topic in astrophysics. If this tag were to be deleted, it would be because we aren't getting many questions about this (not always a good reason to delete a tag imo)

[asteroids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asteroids) ditto. And in this case we are getting questions about it.

[aircraft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) A rather vast topic in fluid dynamics.

[gauss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauss-law) We get enough questions about this. If there were more [faradays-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faradays-law) questions, that tag could be created too, IMO.

Comment: Thanks. But what does "ditto" stand for ? .

Comment: @Dimension10 "same as above"

Comment: The problem with [tag:aircraft] is that         it doesn't need a separate tag for that .       Besides, it may convincve people that posting engineering questions here is a good idea, which it isn't.    Same for [tag:graphene]   . It could well go into the solid state physics tags .  And [tag:gauss-law] could be merged into  one of the other  em tags .

Comment: @Dimension10 It's sort of an engineering tag, yes, but by and large the set of questions under that tag are different enough to get their own tag imo.

Comment: I generally agree with all the comments in this answer. The only thing I dont understand is why [aircraft](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aircraft) is a fluid dynamics tag? Applications of it I can imagine would rather be about engineering, so it is not a keyword often used by physicists.

Comment: @Dilaton Remember that all tags on the site are in the context of physics. You're both right, aircraft questions will usually be engineering, which is a valid cause for removal (because it attracts OT stuff). However, within the context of physics a question about aircraft is (almost always) fluid dynamics. Though it still is removable/mergeable then. tpg2114 usually lurks in that tag, I'll see what he thinks.

Comment: My thoughts on [tag:aircraft]: It's not limited to fluid-dynamics in theory, but also propulsion/combustion, control theory, material science, newtonian-mechanics, etc.. So I wouldn't say it's a useless/redundant tag because it's so much more than fluid-dynamics, even if current questions don't appear to indicate that.

Comment: @tpg2114:  If it were to apply to all that; it would be an engineering tag .

Comment: @Dimension10 Not really, tpg is talking about the physics of it. There's engineering too, but his point is that aircraft _in the context of physics_ is not a tiny topic.

Comment: @Manishearth: He's talking about the fact that all those stuff apply to aircrafts, engineering , .

Comment: I want a tag for [tag:bus], [tag:car], [tag:taxi], [tag:auto-rickshaw], [tag:horse-carriage], [tag:wagon], [tag:elephant-ride], [tag:camel-ride], [tag:donkey-ride], [tag:submarine], [tag:ship], [tag:school-bus], [tag:kidnapper], [tag:cruise-ship], [tag:feet], [tag:bicycle], [tag:unicycle], [tag:cycle], [tag:tricycle], [tag:quadrocycle], [tag:quintocycle], [tag:bike], [tag:scooter], [tag:boat], [tag:speed-boat], [tag:train] (probably even separate tags for each of the names as it is called in different countries...)  , . . .  .    . ';

Comment: @Dimension10 Do they have a lot of physics behind them? Not really. Those tags don't work because there's a very small pool of questions you can ask about them. The physics of flight is _very_ complex and can spawn many  questions. And that's just the physics of flight.

Comment: By base point here is that there are 50 _physics_ questions tagged with it. That itself can show how much physics is behind it.

Comment: @Manishearth: They do . . . As much as aircraft .   Like, does friction   help a horse carraige ? A kidnapper ? .

Comment: @Manishearth: BUT, if it applies to all that, that would mean that it is talking about *engineering*.

Comment: @Dimension10 But friction doesn't apply to _only_ a horse carriage. There's a lot of physics specific to aircraft.

Comment: I don't see why it's engineering. Yes, when looked at _out of context_ , "aircraft" questions would be mainly engineering qs. However, on this site we only accept _physics_ questions, so _in context_ the tag basically means "the physics of flight and other things specific to airplanes"

Comment: @Dimension10 Combustion isn't engineering only and certainly applies to aircraft. The fluid dynamics is obvious that it's physics. Material science could be physics as well if posed correctly. Control theory is really the only one that I might have trouble coming up with a physics-only based question, but even there it might be possible. Something along the lines of "What causes flat spin and why is it unrecoverable?" The answer to that is entirely physics based and would have to include control theory, among other things.

Comment: @tpg2114: I meant that if applies to *all* of that/ , then it is engi8neering.

Comment: @Dimension10 So something that applies to multiple _physics_ topics is engineering? By that logic Lagrangian mechanics is engineering.

Comment: @Dimension10 By what logic? What says that a tag that encompasses multiple sub-fields forces it to be about engineering?

Comment: @tpg2114: @ Manishearth:   BECAUSE,    material-science, fluid-dynamics, etc. are subjects of physics. But aircraft, an application of theiese stuff, is a subject of engineering .

Comment: @Dimension10 To show counter examples -- [tag:mathematical-physics] and [tag:experimental-physics] cover multiple sub-fields including propulsion/combustion, fluid dynamics, control theory, material science. The same sub-fields as aircraft. So are those also engineering?

Comment: @tpg2114: Irrelevant.

Comment: @Dimension10 Except that there is a lot of physics _specific to aircraft_. Again, _the tag does not mean "questions about aircraft", it means "physics questions abut aircraft"_ A tag need not be a physics topic to work.

Comment: @Dimension10 I think you mean irrefutable. But let's look at other examples. [tag:stars] and [tag:planets] have multiple sub-fields, and could be thought of as "applications" of gravity, newtonian-mechanics, and so on. So are those also "engineering" and/or redundant?

Comment: @tpg2114: Nope, irrelevant, because it ignores   http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/redundant-tags-iii/4735?noredirect=1#comment13184_4735 .

Comment: @Manishearth: No, you're ignoring the clarification: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/redundant-tags-iii/4735?noredirect=1#comment13184_4735 . (P.S. Lag. Mech. is a topic in physics, so that's differnet.)

Comment: @tpg2114: And stars and planets aren't engineering, because they aren't manmade , clearly .