# general-physics: a generally terrible tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, blacklist-request

[general-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-physics) is one of the worst tags I have ever seen. It is a cesspit of filth and agony for good stout-hearted reviewers. It is worthy of burnination with fire.

---

Okay, a little more seriously: most of the questions I'm seeing should be retagged/could be retagged. The tag is ridiculous and unnecessary. I'm beginning some edits (not too many of course; don't want to flood the active tab) to start cleaning it up a little.

But I have no idea why it shouldn't be burninated. The tag excerpt says

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG if a more descriptive tag applies.

Uhm...when would a more descriptive tag *not* apply? Thoughts?

Also, I should point out that [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) has already been burninated/removed for all time. How is [general-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-physics) any different?

Another also: [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5032/121464) there's a score of six in favor of burnination. And yet nothing was done...

Comment: [tag:physics] was removed because it's the name of the site. That's standard practice network-wide.

Comment: @DavidZ, aside from that, it would include within its scope all questions on the site, just like [tag:general-physics] - forget about the tag warning (DO NOT USE if more descriptive tag applies), it's not really followed.

Comment: *"a cesspit of filth and agony"* Slight hyperbole for the win.

Comment: @heather (2 comments up) Of course [tag:physics] would include all questions on the site, that's the reason it's not allowed. [tag:general-physics] is different though. That "general" means something; not "physics in general", but it's referring to "interdisciplinary" questions that mix different fields and can't be accurately classified by subfield tags. That was the idea behind it, anyway. In practice, I agree that the tag is doing more harm than good and it's not useful.

Comment: Generally speaking, tag burninate requests should go [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4768/2451).

Comment: July 27, 2017: [tag:general-physics] tag now officially blacklisted.