# Let's eat up another tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Can we burninate [food](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food)? [Here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4905/121464) there were three votes in favor and no dissenters. Yes, there are many questions tagged with it, but really, [food](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) isn't a good tag - the questions are about what's happening *with* the food, and that's what should be described in tags.

Comment: I don't think "burninate" is a word.

Comment: @0celoñe7 would you prefer 'destroy with fire'?

Comment: I would prefer something altogether less violent.

Comment: @0celoñe7 [Burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=burninate) is a word, at least on stack exchange.

Comment: Generally speaking, tag burninate & blacklist requests should go [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4768/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic 1. can I just point out that you marked these two questions as a duplicate of an old question that has multiple tags upvoted enough for burnination and yet nothing's been done? 2. And also may I point out that it's rather hard for people to see that question and vote because it's so old?

Comment: @heather: 1. [See this comment](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/tag-burninate-requests-for-voting#comment37786_4768). 2. Right. Hopefully the old question becomes more visible with the duplicate link.

Comment: @Qmechanic considering the recent chat discussion, can this tag be considered for burnination and blacklisting and the duplicate-close be removed? I should point out it's got a pretty good consensus - 6 upvotes and no downvotes here.

Comment: Hopefully, tag b&b will move faster forward after all the recent discussion. It seems best to collect all b&b requests in different answers in the _same_ [thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4768/2451). Then it is also easier to find them. Moreover, e.g. it was suggested in the past by one person to b&b the following tags: temperature, coulomb-branch, pressure, speed, acceleration, capacitance, angular-momentum, momentum, mass, x-ray, mole. It seems too much if they had went into separate meta posts!

Comment: @Qmechanic that was 4 years ago - I think it's best to have separate meta posts, and that's what was decided in the chat session.

Comment: That is [disputed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39023884#39023884), and decision is delayed to a later chat session.