# How can we suggest synonyms to tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I have seen that tags have synonyms of it under it's description.

How can I suggest a tag synonym?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4007/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need 2500 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) to create and vote on tag synonyms.

However, it's generally much easier to ping a mod in chat or propose it [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/tag-synonyms-for-voting?rq=1), since nobody really monitors the synonyms.