# That tensor from GR - what do we call it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

You know the one I mean, T<sub>μν</sub>.<sup>1</sup> Is it the stress-energy tensor, or the energy-momentum tensor? This is for the purposes of tags, where having both is redundant. This was brought up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9961168#9961168), and there is a [proposal](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4446) on our little-visited tag synonyms page. However, it was pointed out there that the idea of just combining everything into [stress-energy-momentum-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress-energy-momentum-tensor) won't work due to character limits.

Moreover, I dare anyone to claim with a straight face that they would *actually* say "stress-energy-momentum tensor" in conversation.

I therefore propose that **one** of [stress-energy-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress-energy-tensor) or [energy-momentum-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-momentum-tensor) be taken to be "standard," with the other made a synonym. My understanding is that either tag can then be applied, with the synonym silently being replaced, no harm done, no retagging effort necessary.

Rather than proposing a synonym on my own, only to have no one look at that page anyway,<sup>2</sup> I figure this proposal should get some community consensus as to which way the replacement should go. I personally grew up learning that "stress-energy" was a tensor and "energy-momentum" was a 4-vector, but perhaps I'm in the minority, or perhaps there's good reason to differentiate as much as possible the stress-energy tensor of relativity from the stress tensor of mechanics.

Vote below as you see appropriate, or add your own original thoughts in another answer.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I am fully aware that string of symbols refers to an unspecified *component* of a tensor, and not an actual tensor. Mathematically precise people, please don't hurt me. Everyone else, I still reserve the right to admonish you for conflating these two things :P

<sup>2</sup> There are [plenty of other suggestions there](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175) - interested users should vote on them!

Comment: I suggest we call it `Geoffrey`.

Comment: No but I've only seen the energy-momentum 4-vector, I'll be attending a GR course next semester. So I'm not in a position to judge, really. However, I would go for stress-energy-tensor on the basis of causing less confusion alone. Energy-momentum is a SR 4-vector, stress-energy a GR tensor. That makes for a nice, clear distinction.

Comment: "Moreover, I dare anyone to claim with a straight face that they would actually say "stress-energy-momentum tensor" in conversation." I do.

Comment: How about mass-energy-momentum-pressure-stress tensor?

Comment: @BenCrowell: The Stress-Energy-Momentum Tensor involves mass (multiplied by $c_0^2$), momentum, shear stress, and, pressure. So, I would classify pressure and shear stress as "stress" so stress-mass-momentum tensor. 28 characeters... What about sigma-m-p tensor? 16 characters only!

Comment: What about tensor-describing-energy-often-called-the-stress-energy-tensor-or-the-energy-momentum-tensor-or-the-stress-energy-momentum-tensor-or-in-short-comma-the-s-e-m-tensor-or-the-1-by-kappa-einstein-tensor-open-bracket-by-the-einstein-field-equations-or-in-short-comma-the-e-f-e-G-underscore-open-brace-backslash-mu-backslash-nu-close-brace-divided-by-kappa-is-equal-to-T-underscore-open-brace-backslash-mu-backslash-nu-close-brace-close-bracket-and-is-also-called-G-underscore-open-brace-backslash-mu-backslash-nu-close-brace-divided-by-kappa-or-the-einstein-tensor-divided-by-kappa ?

Comment: That was 590 characters (I minus-ed the things other than the-tags.)

Comment: Personally, I haven't read enough physics texts to have an overview of what is more common. But I would like to point out that Wikipedia already redirects Energy momentum tensor to Stress-energy tensor, for what it's worth. They may not be a particularly true source of knowledge, but the fact is that people who are not well familiar with a term frequently search it there, so they may have an influence of what gets to be the more popular term for the broad mass of search engine users.

Comment: Have a nice red [status-completed] tag :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would call it [tag:energy-momentum-density-flow-tensor].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's go with [stress-energy-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress-energy-tensor) as the preferred version and administer the synonymization [energy-momentum-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-momentum-tensor) → [stress-energy-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress-energy-tensor).

[Number of unfiltered Google hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stress%E2%80%93energy+tensor%22): About 117,000 hits.

Comment: I agree with this. I have heard/read of SE much more than EM. I dunno why, because to me momentum is usually a much more fundamental thing than stress :P (Yes, I know the context of stress in GR and it's not exactly stress)

Comment: I think "stress-energy tensor" is by far the more common usage. Penrose is an example of someone who prefers "energy-momentum tensor."

Comment: June 30th, 2013: SET proposal leads EMT proposal by votes 15-2. Synonym EMT->SET created.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go with [energy-momentum-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-momentum-tensor) as the preferred version and administer the synonymization [stress-energy-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress-energy-tensor) → [energy-momentum-tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-momentum-tensor).

[Number of unfiltered Google hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22energy-momentum+tensor%22): About 1,560,000 hits.

Comment: Eh?  I've heard 'energy-momentum vector' of course, but tensor?  Who says that?

Comment: @user1504: You asked _Who says that?_ It is very common. See e.g. Peskin & Schroeder.

Answer (score 0):

It's still wrong to hyphenate it that way.  It should be "stress-energy tensor"....sigh{{Citation needed}}
An underscore as is traditional in Unix should get the tag thing to work:
stress--energy_tensor.  And others.

Comment: Tags need hyphens to work.