# Tag cleanup - pluralization

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

As I was casually going through the list of tags, I noticed several whose pluralization stood out as... off. It seems to me that for non-unique things (so I'm excluding [sun](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sun), [earth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth), etc.) that are not [mass nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) (i.e. concepts, like [energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) or even [simulation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation)), the plural form of the word should be used. By and large this is the case already, but there are a few sore thumbs I suggest replacing. In particular, I suggest the replacements

- [asteroid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asteroid) → [asteroids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asteroids) (cf. [meteoroids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteoroids), [meteors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteors), [meteorites](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorites));
- [exoplanet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exoplanet) → [exoplanets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exoplanets) (cf. [planets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets));
- [nebula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nebula) → [nebulae](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nebulae) (it's not like we live in "*the* Nebula");
- [star](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star) → [stars](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stars) (cf. [planets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets), [neutron-stars](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutron-stars));
- [x-ray](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray) → [x-rays](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-rays) (cf. [gamma-rays](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-rays), [microwaves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microwaves)).

This last one *could* be interpreted as an adjective and thus correct as-is, but the examples show we are being inconsistent at the moment.

On the flip side, there is one that seems unnecessarily pluralized. I suggest

- [stellar-winds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-winds) → [stellar-wind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-wind) (cf. [solar-wind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-wind), [atmosphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere)).

So **(1)** should these changes be made? If so, **(2)** should they be implemented via tag creation/synonymization, or can a mod just silently rename the tags?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451

Comment: I agree x 6. Mods can merge, which can be (ab)used to rename.

Comment: Also, [tag:neutrino].

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. This can be done with the mod synonymification tool - no need to go through the whole process of proposing a suggestion when it's such an obvious correspondence.

I'll leave this for a day or so just in case anyone does have comments, and then make the changes.

mmm, synonymification :-)

Comment: I created the above 5 synonyms, and changed all stellar-winds posts to singular case.

Comment: OK, thanks. (I was just about to do it myself.)