# About synonymous tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

While asking asking a question I noticed that there are two similar tags [weak-interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-interaction) and [weak-interactions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-interactions) which leads to question for their necessity. Should any of these be deleted? If not why?

Comment: I would prefer the singualr version as the survivor.

Comment: They are already synonyms.

Comment: They are already marked as [tag synonyms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/weak-interaction/synonyms) where the plural gets mapped into the singular when used...

Comment: But while typing these two appeared separately.

Comment: Sure -- [when a synonym is added to a post, it is silently changed to the target](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). So which ever you chose, it will end up as [tag:weak-interaction].

Comment: Ok thanks I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [weak-force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-force) tag and the [weak-interactions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-interactions) tag were merged into the [weak-interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-interaction) tag in 2014, partly spurred by [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4677/2451) 2013 meta post.

General tip: Other synonym tags can be suggested on [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451) meta page.

Comment: Can one also un-suggest synonyms?

Comment: Alternatively, one may try the hbar chat room.