# Should we rename the teleportation tag to quantum-teleportation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm pretty sure there's a formal mechanism to suggest tag synonyms but I can't find it and no one ever votes there anyway, so:

- should we rename [teleportation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teleportation) to [quantum-teleportation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-teleportation) and make the former redirect to the latter?

It would make it equally easy to find and relatively clearer on what it entails.

Comment: There *is* a formal way to suggest synonyms, namely [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest), but that page is so well-hidden that very few people use it...

Comment: Ah, hidden at the bottom of [the tags page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags) ─ I looked for it but I could only find it via google search. A̶n̶d̶ ̶I̶ ̶s̶t̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶g̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶u̶g̶g̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶v̶o̶t̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶e̶x̶i̶s̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶u̶g̶g̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶.̶ And [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86020/how-do-i-suggest-a-tag-synonym) the suggestion mechanism is entirely disconnected from that page. Of course.

Comment: General tip: For users without sufficient privileges, synonym tags can also be suggested on [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451) meta page.

Comment: FWIW, I have had a link to the page ACM linked to in my profile for a while now, mostly to advertise that it exists.

Comment: But that means I can't post my sci-fi teleportation questions!

Comment: We might find a non-QM way to teleport in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't think of anything else that the [teleportation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teleportation) tag would be used for, at least not within the scope of actual physics (and hence of this site). Unless there is some such thing, yes, I'd say go for it.

Of course there do seem to be some existing questions with the [teleportation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teleportation) tag which [quantum-teleportation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-teleportation) would *not* apply to. Most of them are probably off topic, and any others should have the tag removed. So we may want to do a bit of cleanup before actually making the switch.

Comment: July 15th, 2017: Tag synonym mapping [tag:teleportation] →[tag:quantum-teleportation] created.