# Merge [group-representations] with [representation-theory]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

This is the description of the [group-representations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-representations) tag:

> Use as a synonym to the [representation-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theory) tag

So we may want to merge them together already.

Comment: Rather than opening a new meta post for every tag synonym, this meta question should have been a meta answer [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451).

Comment: sorry I didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Representation theory is more general than group representations as it e.g. includes Lie algebra representations.
2. I have just made the [group-representations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-representations) tag a synonym of the [representation-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theory) tag. (It was proposed in 2016 with currently 1 upvote.) Depending on feed-back from the community, we can later merge or undo the synonym.